# Warnings still show up even with message=FALSE in RMarkdown

Tags: r

I used `message=FALSE` in an `Rmd` file and there are still warnings showing up. Any idea what went wrong?

```
{r message=FALSE}
comparison_data <- spooky_trainining_tidy_1n %>%
dplyr::select(author, word) %>%
dplyr::anti_join(stop_words) %>%
dplyr::count(author,word, sort = TRUE)

comparison_data %>%
reshape2::acast(word ~ author, value.var = "n", fill = 0) %>%
comparison.cloud(colors = c("red", "violetred4", "rosybrown1"),
               random.order = F,
               scale=c(7,.5),
               rot.per = .15,
               max.words = 200)
```

A bunch of warnings show up such as this:

> ## Warning in comparison.cloud(., colors = c("red", "violetred4", "rosybrown1"), : heart could not be fit on page. It will not be plotted.

Comment: Where does the `comparison.cloud` function came from? If the function authors didn't use the `warning()` or `message()` function to properly emit the warning, then rmarkdown can't catch it properly.

Comment: It's from the wordcloud package